# Taking parts out of a string, how?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

So I have a server that receives a connection with the message being converted to a string, I then have this string split between by the spaces

Comment: Did you take a look at [string.Trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: Manipulate the splitted strings, and then join them later

Comment: @Steve I don't think trim will help - the complaint appears to be that there is a double space in the line

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't think I have understood what they are asking. :-)

Comment: I gotta admit, I'm struggling a bit too!

Comment: I do apologise, I have included mroe to help understand the problem and the process I explained

Comment: Find index of the second word and then substring from that index 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846580/regex-to-match-the-second-word-of-a-sentence-and-trim-leading-white-space

Comment: And if you remove the problem from the start? Just use the parameter StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmtpyEntries when you call split. The rogue initial space will be omitted directly by Split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the empty space using TrimStart() method.
Something like this:

```
    string text = "Hello World";
    string[] textSplited = text.Split(' ');

    string result = text.Replace(textSplited[0], "").TrimStart();
```

Comment: You don't need to use string split at all(and it's a big waste of resources) if you're just removing the first word

Comment: I will try your method also Caius, It seems efficient. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

So you have a line:

```
var line = "hello world my name is bob";
```

And you don't want "world" or "is", so you want:

```
"hello my name bob"
```

If you split to a list, remove the things you don't want and recombine to a line, you won't have extraneous spaces:

```
var list = line.Split().ToList();
list.Remove("world");
list.Remove("is");
var result = string.Join(" ", list);
```

Or if you know the exact index positions of your list items, you can use `RemoveAt`, but remove them in order from highest index to lowest, because if you e.g. want to remove 1 and 4, removing 1 first will mean that the 4 you wanted to remove is now in index 3.. Example:

```
var list = line.Split().ToList();
list.RemoveAt(4); //is
list.RemoveAt(1); //world
var result = string.Join(" ", list);
```

If you're seeking a behavior that is like string.Replace, which removes all occurrences, you can use RemoveAll:

```
var line = "hello is world is my is name is bob";

var list = line.Split().ToList();
list.RemoveAll(w => w == "is"); //every occurence of "is"
var result = string.Join(" ", list);
```

Comment: Note that `list.Remove(list[0])` is very similar to `list.RemoveAt(0)`  The `RemoveAt` is faster while the `Remove(list[0])` will remove other words that are equal to the first element, which may or may not be wanted.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for the nudge; minor correction that Remove removes the earliest only, but you're right to point out that that in itself could be a problem because it doesn't behave like the OP's Replace.

Comment: Ahh, right you are, `Remove` also only removes the first occurrence.  Misleading naming, should be called `RemoveOnce`.  And then there's no reason ever to use `Remove` to take out the first word because `RemoveAt(0)` is so much more efficient.  And `args.Remove(args[i])` for `i > 0` is even more dangerous because it might not even remove the *i*th element at all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to remove the first word and not all repeats of it, a much more efficient way is to use [the overload of split that lets you control the maximum number of splits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char()-system-int32)) (the argument is the maximum number of results, which is one more than the maximum number of splits):

```
string[] arguments = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // split only once
User.data = arguments.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

`arguments[1]` does the right thing when there are "more" arguments, but throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the number of words is zero or one.  That could be fixed without LINQ by `(arguments.Length > 1)? arguments[1]: string.Empty`

Comment: I suppose `User.data = line[(line.IndexOf(' ')+1)..]` (or the substring equivalent) might work too

Comment: @CaiusJard: That will only return only of the spaces separating the first word from the rest of the string, and could also do the unexpected thing in case of leading spaces.  To see the differences between all these approaches, one should use test cases such as `""`, `"   "`, `"hello world"`, `"    hello world"`, `"hello    world"`, `"hello world    "`, `"hello", "hello hello hello"`

Comment: I think they're the same end result.. https://dotnetfiddle.net/kcWTDY, well.. apart from the `""` case, where Split blows up..

Comment: @CaiusJard: Wow I'm misremembering a lot of details today, I thought that `RemoveEmptyEntries` was turned on by default if you didn't specify split options explicitly.

Comment: It must be something in the water. Three times today alone I've looked up which way round SqlDataAdapter's constructor for "string sql, string connection" is, because I just couldn't remember..

Answer (score 0):

If you're just removing the first word of a string, you don't need to use Split at all; doing a Substring after you found the space will be more efficient.

```
var line = ...
var idx = line.IndexOf(' ')+1;
line = line.Substring(idx);
```

or in recent C# versions

```
line = line[idx..];
```